# How to label (set Title) for IIS Express process?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I have a solution with multiple websites and I have been using Cassini for development. When IIS Express came out, I transitioned one of the websites to use it, and everything has been running fine. I just moved another website to use IIS Express and immediately ran into a problem with debugging: IIS Express does not label its processes, so now that I have two of them running, I can't tell them apart in the "Attach to process" dialog.

Is there a way to have IIS Express set the process title? Anyone have any tips for telling multiple IIS Express instances apart for the purposes of attaching the debugger?

**Update**
A round-about way of doing this is to execute "Show all applications" context menu of the IIS Express tray icon and reference the PID from the list when attaching the debugger. Better than nothing, but would be nice if there was a better way.

**Update 2**
I added a connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729475/impossible-to-differentiate-iis-express-instances-when-attaching-debugger

Comment: Show all applications is good enough for me - thanks for the tip

Comment: Connect will just close it as "by design".

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can add this code to start the debugger from inside your page. It's fast and easy, and you can just use a hidden local page to call it and start your debugger.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Answer (score 3):

I run the IISExpress instances from a batch file. The name of the cmd file then shows up as the process name in Attach to Process.

eg: have this in the MySite.cmd file

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /siteid:1`

Would show up in the Title colum in Attach to Process as

`MySite`

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the site id ?

Comment: As far as I know only by going in and checking it in the applicationhost.config file. You can find it in %Your user folder%\Documents\IISExpress\config

You can also run iisexpress.exe with a /site:[site-name] argument instead of using site-id

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget a reference to System.Management ...

```
public static Regex siteNamePattern = new Regex("/site:\"(?<sitename>[^\"]+)\"", RegexOptions.Compiled);

...

var iisExpressSiteNames = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    "select CommandLine, ProcessId from Win32_Process where Name='iisexpress.exe'")
    .Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToDictionary(
    o => int.Parse(o["ProcessId"].ToString()),
    o => siteNamePattern.Match(o["CommandLine"].ToString()).Groups["sitename"].Value
);
```

Comment: This is of course not a ready-made answer to your question, but it could be used to make such an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the need to label the processes for the "attach to process" dialog.  However, there's a workaround for your specific case.

Workaround:

If you have two projects in the same solution you can choose multiple startup projects:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2015

[image: Solution Properties]

Comment: FYI, I don't normally answer with workarounds, but the OP's question could easily be rewritten as "how do I debug multiple solutions at the same time".  Attach to process, would be a valid answer to that with the caveat of the missing title which the OP already pointed out.  But this workaround would also be a valid answer.